# Connection is not private using Google Domains and Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a domain that I purchased from Google and a heroku app that I'm trying to send it to.

I've done the steps in this article: https://www.justinvrooman.com/articles/how-to-use-heroku-with-google-domains

and yet when I try to access the site I get a

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.***.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

What am I doing wrong with my set up or why am I getting this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've enabled SSL in your Rails app but your site doesn't have an SSL certificate configured. To disable SSL, set the following to "false" in your 'config/environments/production.rb' file.

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

In addition, in the same file, don't forget to set your "host" equal to your custom domain.

```
host = 'www.yourdomain.com'
```

If you want to run SSL on a custom domain (e.g. www.example.com) you'll need to purchase and configure an SSL certificate for your domain.

If, however, you are fine using Heroku's domain (e.g. example.herokuapp.com), then you can piggyback on Heroku's SSL certificate.

More info on running SSL on a custom domain through Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: Din't work for me, Using heroku with jekyll. Adde both the config variables but it still shows the same message.